# Writing hello world on extends class

Tags: java

I would like to write program which prints "Hello World", but I like to make class A which prints Hello and class B which prints World. Class B extends A.
How can I get this print?

My code:

```
public class A {

    public String toString(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}

public class B extends A{

    public String tostring(){
        return super().tostring() + "World";
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A first = new A();
        B second = new B();
        System.out.println(first);
        System.out.println(second);

    }

}
```

I tried to wrote this program, but I don't know how to write class B.

Comment: tostring() is not in the super class you have a method called toString() though I presume you ment this

Comment: The syntax is `super.method()`. You mispelled `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class B extends A{

      public String toString(){
         return super.toString() + " World";
      }
   }
```

You should probably keep the same name for both methods as well and add a space as otherwise they will print as one word

Comment: Should also mention OP will need `@Override` on `toString`